# Interpolating Surface in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a polynomial of the form

`z = Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Dx + Ey + F`

In `R`, where the capital letters are constant coefficients.

For the following data

My horizontal axis is: `KSo<-c(0.90,0.95,1.00,1.05,1.10)`

My vertical axis is: `T<-c(1/12,3/12,6/12,1,2,5)`

And the data mapped by `KSo X T` are:

`14.2 13.0 12.0 13.1 14.5`

`14.0 13.0 12.0 13.1 14.2`

`14.1 13.3 12.5 13.4 14.3`

`14.7 14.0 13.5 14.0 14.8`

`15.0 14.4 14.0 14.5 15.1`

`14.8 14.6 14.4 14.7 15.0`

In other words, the observed datum for `(1.00,6/12)` is `12.5`

How would I interpolate, for example, the predicted data for `(0.98,11/12)`?

Edit: I found a nice package, `akima`, with the `bicubic` function, that uses splines. I'd still like to see what people suggest

Comment: Have you researched the problem?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation.  There a straight froward equation to interpolate the unit square.  With the cut command, one can obtain the indexes of the T and KSo.  Please edit your question and add the data mapping as a structure created with the dput command.

Comment: @Dave2e I've researched it but I couldn't find how to do it in R. That article seems to describe interpolating a 1st degree polynomial, but I wanted second degree. I don't know how to attach files to posts here.

Comment: There are 2 options which I an confident about.  Perform the linear interpolation using the neighboring points, if your grid spacing is tight, it should be accurate enough.  Or since you know the shape of the surface, perform a regression analysis on the entire data set to determine the coefficients and then solve analytically.  The other possibility is fitting splines with the nearby points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the two possible suggested solutions.
The original data:

```
KSo<-c(0.90,0.95,1.00,1.05,1.10)
T<-c(1/12,3/12,6/12,1,2,5)
mapping<-c(14.2, 13.0, 12.0, 13.1, 14.5,
           14.0, 13.0, 12.0, 13.1, 14.2,
           14.1, 13.3, 12.5, 13.4, 14.3,
           14.7, 14.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.8,
           15.0, 14.4, 14.0, 14.5, 15.1,
           14.8, 14.6, 14.4, 14.7, 15.0)
mapped<-matrix(mapping, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
```

Here is the linear interpolation solution:

```
#predict
x<-0.98
y<-11/12

#Perform 2D interpolation
#find index along x and y axis
ki<-as.integer(cut(x, KSo, right=FALSE))
Ti<-as.integer(cut(y, T, right=FALSE))

#dx = (x-x1)/(x2-x1)  where x is the point to interpolate to.
# dx will vary from 0 to <1, (or worded differently the % distance between the 2 grid points)
dx<-(x-KSo[ki])/(KSo[ki+1]-KSo[ki])
dy<-(y-T[Ti])/(T[Ti+1]-T[Ti])

#find values and weighed sums of neighboring points
#    equations as per Wikipedia
f00<-mapped[Ti, ki]*(1-dx)*(1-dy)  
#    f(0,0) -weight each corner contributes to the final results
f01<-mapped[Ti+1, ki]*(1-dx)*dy
f10<-mapped[Ti, ki+1]*dx*(1-dy)
f11<-mapped[Ti+1, ki+1]*dx*dy
sum(f00, f10, f01, f11)
```

Same analysis as above but with R's functions

```
ki<-as.integer(cut(x, KSo, right=FALSE))
Ti<-as.integer(cut(y, T, right=FALSE))
ilower<-approx(T, mapped[,ki], y)$y
iupper<-approx(T, mapped[,(ki+1)], y)$y
approx(KSo[ki:(ki+1)], c(ilower, iupper), x)
```

Below is the Regression Model using the entire data set to fit.  Since the data is not perfect fit, the estimated value at a grid point is different than the original specified value.

```
#establish data frame with raw data
df<-data.frame(expand.grid(KSo, T), mapping)
names(df)<-c("KSo", "T", "z")

#Perform regression
model<-lm(z~I(KSo^2)+I(T^2)+KSo*T, data=df)

#Predict results at desired coordinates
dfnew<-data.frame(KSo=c(1, 0.98), T=c(0.5, 0.9166667))
predict(model, dfnew)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is good! But can you please go into more detail how you turned `KSo X T` into a unit square?

Comment: I add few additional comments and I also added a code block on performing the linear interpolation using R's function.  Draw out the 4 neighboring points and then step through the code line by line, it should become clearer